# EF 4.3 Throwing "An error occurred while getting provider info from the dB. caused by EF using an incorrect con. string. Check Inner Excptin."

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using EF 4.3 Code first. Developing EF Code first application and making CRUD operations done really well on my dev box. Real problem started after I moved the code to WCF service test Server. While I'm trying to insert a record I'm getting

> "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct"

Same code in Web Server is working well and its done did by another developer(left the company now), Are there any additional config setting  I should do on IIS or in application config before deploying it to WCF TEST Server.
I mean do I need to install some thing or verify in GAC ?

WCF Server: Windows Server 2008 R2

EF Version : EF 4.3 Code First . Database exists ahead of deployment on WCF test server

Config File :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyApplicationDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"    connectionString="Server=jmicsq10webdev\web_dev;Database=PlEcom;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>

<configSections>   
<section name="entityFramework"   type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
```

I tried also with ProverderName = "system.Data.SqlClient.dll", but didn't fix my problem

Comment: What does the inner exception message say?

Comment: I'm sorry. Current aplication is not logging inner exceptions.I'm changing the it to log in our next release. After trying for while this morning I see there would be a chance of Windows Identity mismatch between WCF Server and Db Server. My local box runs with my acnt and was able perform CRUD operation , WCF Server runs with a different account and cannot perform CRUD operations. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error, so I went and changed from

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

this line to

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcHopitalPatient-20121116125855.mdf"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to the code snippet below

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="PatientDBContext"
        connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Patients.sdf"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>

    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
        Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcHopitalPatient-20121116125855;
        Integrated Security=SSPI;
        AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcHopitalPatient-20121116125855.mdf"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular SqlClient instead of the Compact Edition one?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyApplicationDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"    connectionString="Server=jmicsq10webdev\web_dev;Database=PlEcom;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The string you provided is not for CodeFirst. CodeFirst is using "regular" connstrings. Hence -1 since this information is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, Pawel. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start SQL Server service from control panel. Sometimes the services gets stopped. I had the same problem. reason was that Sql service was not running. starting the services fixed the issue